# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Computer {
    String brand;
    String serialNo;
    int year;
    String type;
    double price;

    public Computer(String a, String b, int c, String d, double e) {
        brand = a;
        serialNo = b;
        year = c;
        type = d;
        price = e;

    }

    public String getbrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public String getserialNo() {
        return serialNo;
    }

    public int getyear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String gettype() {
        return type;
    }

    public double getprice() {
        return price;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList computer = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList notebooklist = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList desktoplist = new LinkedList();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < computerList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter brand ");
            brand = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter serial number ");
            serialNo = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter year manufactured ");
            year = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter type ");
            type = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter price ");
            price = scan.nextDouble();

            Computer data = new Computer(brand, serialNo, year, type, price);
            computerList.insertAtBack(data);
        }
    }

    public class LinkedList {
        private Node first;//the 1st node
        private Node last;//the last node
        private Node current; //if any

        public LinkedList() // default constructor
        {
            first = null;//set the linked list to null
            last = null;
            current = null;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return (first == null);
        }

        public void insertAtBack(Object insertItem) {
            Node newNode = new Node(insertItem);

            if (isEmpty()) {
                first = newNode;
                last = newNode;
            } else {
                last.next = newNode;
                last = newNode;
            }
        }

        public Object getFirst() {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                current = first;
                return current.data;
            }
        }

        public Object getNext() {

            if (current == last) {
                return null;
            } else {
                current = current.next;
                return current.data;
            }

        }

        class Node {
            Object data;
            Node next;

            Node() {
                data = null;
            }

            Node(Object obj) {
                data = obj;
            }

            Node(Object obj, Node a) {
                data = obj;
                a = next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my assignment.i kinda stuck because of 'non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context' error.i dont know what caused it.can someone explain to me? Its this the correct way to use linked list?

Comment: You should improve your code formatting. It's terrible. Now on the topic : somewhere you are trying to access a `non-static` variable or method directly from a static one. This is an error, because static variables/methods does not belong to a specific instance of the object, but to the class itself, so non static methods/variables are not visible from static methods. You can access them only through object instances

Comment: BTW it is not a good practice to give the same name(`LinkedList`) to your classes which exists in JDK.

Comment: And it is also not good practice to declare container (`LinkedList` and `Node`) class inside your entity - `Computer`.

Comment: when you are using a non-static variable (like 'year' here) in an static method, you must say that this variable is for which Object, thats not static so it's belongs to a specific object: try it: in your main (as static method) make an objects of Computer class named 'A' then call year like this: A.getYear()

Comment: i'm still new to linked list.forgive me if my coding is terrible.i still don understand what i have to do.can someone show me example?

Comment: (1) You have to declare `brand`, `serialNo`, etc. variables to use in your `for` loop. You can't access the ones that are defined as members of your class because they are not static. (2) Your linkedList class doesn't have a `size()` method. You have to define one if you want to call it. (3) The name of your `computer` variable doesn't match the name of the `computerList` variable you are trying to use in your `for` loop.

Comment: A person made your question duplicated so I cannot write an example in answers!